# Is it possible to render two video streams simultaneously on a single SurfaceView?

Tags: android, surfaceview

Is it possible to render two video streams simultaneously, using different "sections" of a single `SurfaceView`?

I have made sample code that renders two videos simultaneously using two SurfaceViews side-by-side, but I am wondering if it is possible to have both videos play on the same `SurfaceView`.

Using a `MediaPlayer`, you can set either the SurfaceHolder or the Surface itself as the display. I believe the code to achieve what I am asking would be inside of the `surfaceCreated` method:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    mediaPlayerTop.setDisplay(holder);
    mediaPlayerBottom.setDisplay(holder);

    play();
}
```

However, simply setting both `MediaPlayer`s to the same Surface results in an `IllegalStateException` when you try to `prepare` the second `MediaPlayer` (this is ignoring the fact that they'd probably overlap eachother anyways because I am not setting the position anywhere).

Basically, is what I am trying to achieve possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but it takes some effort.

The basic plan is to direct the output of MediaPlayer to a SurfaceTexture, which converts each incoming frame to a GLES texture.  You then render that to the SurfaceView, drawing a rect that fills half the view.  You do the same thing for the other MediaPlayer.

The pieces you need can be found in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika), e.g. the "texture from camera" Activity takes a video stream from the camera preview, converts it to a GLES texture, and renders it to a SurfaceView.

Simply directing the output of two MediaPlayers to separate SurfaceViews is much easier, but less flexible.

Surfaces are endpoints in a producer-consumer pair.  There can only be one producer at a time, so you can't simply direct two MediaPlayers at a single SurfaceView.

Comment: Is it possible to play 2 webrtc streams simultaneously in a single Activity via a streaming connection in Android