# Multiple videos on one Surface

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I have a single, fullscreen `SurfaceView`. And I have multiple network streams with h264 video which I can decode using `MediaCodec`. Is it possible to specify to which coordinates of the `Surface` will the video be rendered? So I can create kind of video mozaic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270328/is-it-possible-to-render-two-video-streams-simultaneously-on-a-single-surfacevie/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You'll need to use multiple `SurfaceTexture`s instead, one per video decoder, and render all the textures into one view using Open GL.

See https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html for more explanations on how this works; in particular, each `Surface` can only have one producer and one consumer.

Answer (score 0):

In single SurfaceView - no. For more information you can explore SurfaceView source code. Maybe some effect of mosaic you can create using the few SurfaceView and adding special byte buffer trimer - to combine one video to several SV and getting full video.

But anyway! It will not be a good idea, if we talk about performance.